# Godot graphing and dynamic y-axis alterations

Tags: godot

I am currently trying to create a line graph to track the total cash income in an idle game I am making. The line graph functions, and tracks the total cash over time, but once it reaches the max y-value on the y-axis (in this case 500) it exceeds the bounds of the graph. I am trying to determine if there is a way to dynamically adjust the value of the y-axis to the max (so far) total cash value and squash the values on the graph at the same time, and then do this anytime going forward that the value of the cash total exceeds the max value of the y-axis.

The values of the graph are contained within a PackedVector2Array, and are cleared every 60 seconds.

The current range of the x-axis is 1000
The starting range of the y-axis is 500

I have coded in the increase in the y-axis value already. Variables like cashValue, xRange, and yRange are contained in a separate GlobalScript that is preloaded.

This is the code I currently have:

```
extends Line2D

var xVal = 0
var customPoints = PackedVector2Array()
var updateTimer = 0

func _ready():
    #Setup for graph
    self.default_color = Color(1, 0, 0)
    self.width = 2
    customPoints.append(Vector2(xVal, GlobalScript.cashValue))
    update_line_graph()
    set_process(true)
    #Setup for labels
    var yAxisLabelString = "%.2f" % GlobalScript.yRange
    var xAxisLabelString = "%.2f" % GlobalScript.xRange
    $YAxisLabel.text = yAxisLabelString
    $XAxisLabel.text = xAxisLabelString

func _process(delta):
    updateTimer += delta

    #Forces the graph to update only once per second
    if updateTimer >= 1.0:
        xVal += 10
        #Clears graph if x-axis value (time) exceeds 500
        if xVal > GlobalScript.xRange:
            xVal = 0
            customPoints.clear()
        
        #Increases y-axis label to whatever highest cashValue has been
        if GlobalScript.cashValue > GlobalScript.yRange:
            GlobalScript.yRange = GlobalScript.cashValue
            var yAxisLabelString = "%.2f" % GlobalScript.yRange
            $YAxisLabel.text = yAxisLabelString
            customPoints.append(Vector2(xVal, -(GlobalScript.cashValue)))
            update_line_graph()
        else: if GlobalScript.cashValue <= GlobalScript.yRange:
            customPoints.append(Vector2(xVal, -(GlobalScript.cashValue)))
            update_line_graph()

        updateTimer = 0

func update_line_graph():
    self.set_points(customPoints)
```

Comment: Seems like `Vector2(xVal, -(GlobalScript.cashValue))` is where you map the current cash value to a pixel position. 1 cash = 1 pixel. I guess the easiest from there is to `scale` the entire node based on the global yRange and how large (in pixels) you want your graph